# SSL certificate for Grails

Tags: ssl, grails, glassfish

I developed and grails application using `Grails 2.5.1` , before making it live i want to test the SSL certificate but not with the grails self-signed certificate, is there any free `CA websites` that generate free certificates for testing, also i need to know how to add the generated certificate to my grails application, because nearly all what i found talking about adding the below lines to the `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.tomcat.keystorePath ="${grailsSettings.baseDir}/conf/ssl/keystore.jks"
grails.tomcat.keystorePassword = "keystorePassword"
```

and for instance in production i will use `GlassFish server` how i can add this certificate to it, are there any tutorials on this subject.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest  that you instead put some thing like nginx in frontof tomcat/glassfish and configure nginx for ssl

Answer (score 0):

You may get as lot certificates as you need at https://letsencrypt.org/.

About installing certificates into Glassfish you may start from here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyba.html

or from here
https://ssl.comodo.com/support/certificate-installation-glassfish-4x.php

And a lot of information is [here](https://www.google.ru/search?q=GlassFish%20server%20adding%20certificates&oq=GlassFish%20server%20adding%20certificates&aqs=chrome..69i57.6748j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)